# Unprotecting specific cells in protected range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an arbitrary range of values. The cell starting at F25 gets populating until maximum F20000. The values in the ranges can be any whole number including zero.

For cells with non-zero values, I want to protect and not allow any user/editor to edit the value. For cells with zero, I want to unprotect the cell and allow users (specific or all) to edit the value. `newRow` is the number of rows.

So I first protect the entire range:

```
var range = newSheet.getRange("F25:F" + (newRow-1));
var protection = range.protect();
```

Then loop over the values in that range:

```
var values = range.getValues();
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { 
  if (values[i][0] === 0) {
     // I want to only unprotect specific cells here
  }
}
```

What I tried/want to try - where `editors` is the list of users with access to the sheet:

```
protection.removeEditor(editors[i]);
protection.setUnprotectedRanges([values[i][0].getA1Notation()]);
```

But I'm getting this error when I try the first method. And I believe it's incorrect as it will remove access for the entire range?:

```
Unexpected error while getting the method or property removeEditor on object SpreadsheetApp.Protection
```

For the second method, I believe it won't work as I can't access the address of a value but it's basically what I want to be done - get specific address of cell with zero value and unprotect it but keep rest of non-zero value range protected.

Another way is looping over it and protecting each cell by its own and ignoring zero values but that took a significant time to run.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a sample script as an answer by guessing your expected result. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your following situation,

> For cells with non-zero values, I want to protect and not allow any user/editor to edit the value.

And

> What I tried/want to try - where editors is the list of users with access to the sheet:

> ```js
> protection.removeEditor(editors[i]);
> protection.setUnprotectedRanges([values[i][0].getA1Notation()]);
> ```

I guessed your goal is as follows.

- You want to protect all cells without a value of `0` in "F25:F" from all other users.

In this case, how about the following method?

- In your situation, I think that you want to protect all cells without a value of `0` in "F25:F" from all other users. In this case, it seems that you don't want to protect the cells of columns "A" to "G", "F1:F24", "G1:(end of column)". In this modification, I used this situation. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET).forEach(p => p.remove());
  const protect = sheet.protect();
  protect.removeEditors(protect.getEditors());
  const range = sheet.getRange("F25:F" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const rowStart = range.getRow();
  const rangeList = range.getValues().reduce((ar, [f], i) => {
    if (f === 0) {
      ar.push(`F${i + rowStart}`);
    }
    return ar;
  }, []);
  const unprotectedRanges = [
    sheet.getRange("A1:E"),
    sheet.getRange("F1:F24"),
    sheet.getRange(1, 7, sheet.getMaxRows(), sheet.getMaxColumns() - 6),
    ...(rangeList.length > 0 ? sheet.getRangeList(rangeList).getRanges() : [])
  ];
  protect.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotectedRanges);
}
```

- When this script is run, only the cells without a value of `0` in "F25:F" of the sheet are protected. Other cells are not protected.

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the protected cells can be edited by only the owner of the Spreadsheet. If you want to add other users as the editor, please modify `protect.removeEditors(protect.getEditors());` to your actual situation.

#### Reference:

- [setUnprotectedRanges(ranges)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#setunprotectedrangesranges)

Answer (score 1):

From this answer:

> https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112147/how-to-remove-protection-on-a-range-using-scripts-in-google-spreadsheets

You cannot store the protection as a variable you must loop over all protections in the sheet to find the matching protection. For example:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; // assuming you want the first sheet
var protections = sheet.getProtections();
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
  if (protections[i].getDescription() == 'Protect column A') {
    protections[i].remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: So when I create `protection`, I have to read it back using `sheet.getProtections()`? But in that case, if I remove `protections[i]`, it will remove unprotect that entire range instead of cases where it's zero, no?